# Unable to Writing data in Delta Format

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I have upload the parquet data format file into databricks file System. Now I want to to store this parquet file data into Delta Table (Delta Format).  But unable to do. My code is:

```
spark.read.option("inferschema",true).option("header",true).csv("/FileStore/tables/ExecutiveSummary.txt").
write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/FileStore/tables/delta_train/")
```

It show me syntax error. What is the issue in this ?

I am using databricks community edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't simply split code into two lines.  Your first line is finishing with `.` character - it's incorrect in python.  You need to use either this variant (with `\` as continuation marker, and `.` put to the `write` word):

```py
spark.read.option("inferschema",true).option("header",true).csv("/FileStore/tables/ExecutiveSummary.txt") \
  .write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/FileStore/tables/delta_train/")
```

or this variant, with `()` around your expression, but still you need to put `.` in correct place:

```
(spark.read.option("inferschema",true).option("header",true).csv("/FileStore/tables/ExecutiveSummary.txt")
  .write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/FileStore/tables/delta_train/"))
```

Comment: any clue on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74035832/exception-occured-while-writing-delta-format-in-aws-s3 ?